# Handling related dimension values

Tags: android, android-layout

Some of the dimension values in my android project are related to each other. For example, the corner radius of a rectangle is always half of the width. Is it possible for some dimension values to be automatically determined based on some other values?

Comment: No. Resource files don't perform calculations. They are just plain xml data files. You'll have to manage that programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use databinding library with a biniding adapter to do whatever you want (like halving other dimensions resources).